# Compatibility of embedded device with USB drives

Tags: usb, embedded, data-storage

It seems to be a frequent problem with embedded MCUs and USB drives having compatibility issues. Some type of drives from certain vendors work, others do not. Is there a trick to getting high compatibility. Does this problem lie entirely in the choice of driver on the embedded side or is it often electrical as well, USB drivers / Vendors not meeting USB spec?

Anyone sitting on good information here where the problem generally lies and how to make best decisions here to maximize compatibility? Currently maintaining a stm32 embedded MCU which can only support a narrow selection of USB drives. Others USB sticks simply arent detected by the driver, especially newer ones.

I will add that here the STM32 USB Host stack is being used and a basic fatfs driver. No operating system.

Comment: *Others simply arent detected* - not detected by what? Some kind of OS? Some custom firmware? This question lacks details. The hardware is unlikely cause.

Comment: USB has a heavy software stack, so some baremetal and rtos implementations may not support the entire zoo of USB features or be the most robust , even if the hardware is wired up or controller has the right logic to do it.

Comment: You've got three problems: (a) Power, (b) embedded USB stack support for different subclasses of the USB Mass Storage class, (c) non-conformance of either host stack or USB device to the USB specification for the particular subclass the device describes itself as.  "Some USB sticks simple aren't detected, especially newer ones" suggests that the host doesn't support UASP.